# test instance attributes with python

Tags: python, unit-testing, beautifulsoup

I am writing a unit test to determine if an attribute is properly set during the instantiation of my parser object.  Unfortunetly the only way that I can think to do it is to use     `self.assertTrue(p.soup)`
 I haven't slung any python in awhile, but that doesn't seem like a very clear way to check that the instance attribute was properly set.  Any ideas on how to improve it?

Here is my test class:

```
class ParserTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.uris = ctd.Url().return_urls()
        self.uri = self.uris['test']

    def test_create_soup(self):
        p = ctd.Parser(self.uri)
        self.assertTrue(p.soup)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
    # suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(UrlTest)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

Here is my Parser class that I am testing

```
class Parser():

    def __init__(self, uri):
        self.uri = uri
        self.soup = self.createSoup()

    def createSoup(self):
        htmlPage = urlopen(self.uri)
        htmlText = htmlPage.read()
        self.soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlText)
        return BeautifulSoup(htmlText)
```

I got in the bad habot over the past few years of not unit testing, so I am fairly new to the topic.  Any good resources to look at for an in depth explaination of unit testing in Python would be appreciated.  I look at the standard library unittest documentation, but that really didn't help much...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `p.soup` attribute needs to be instance of BeautifulSoup you can explicitly [check](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertIsInstance) its type

`self.assertIsInstance(p.soup, BeautifulSoup)`